# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: W4r in React Native

Tags: react-native, referenceerror

After adding the new files from a different folder I got this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: W4r
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is running from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it, and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

I did not find the "W4r" in anywhere in my code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove node_modules folder
2. Install dependencies (npm i)
3. Close android emulator & close metro window
4. cd android && gradlew clean
5. npx react-native start --reset-cache
6. After "Metro" opens, close it
7. npm run android

I try this when my env no respond, hope its help you.

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: @rohit-barate it would be good to get your project to help solve the mistake